# How do I change the my website icon in the search results page of a web browser?

Tags: icon, favicon

I tried looking trough Youtube videos and other webs, but still couldn´t change it.
[image: Example of icon page with Google]

Comment: I'd guess either they use the favicon or `<meta property="og:image"` or maybe even something else you can configure in [the search console](https://developers.google.com/search). If you can find out what that is we can help you get WordPress to serve it.

Comment: the site icon in settings/customizer/site icon block is usually hat sets this in WordPress, but googles documentation should give you the specifics